# how can I create a react component for paypal in-context express checkout?

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I am quite new to reacjs and stuggle to create a reactjs component for [paypal's in-context express checkout windows](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/#basic-integration) - it is simple to do in plain javascript but not sure how I can create a component and use it in similar way as [react-stripe-checkout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-checkout)? thanks

Comment: I had the same issue setting up Paypal in my React application. [Stripe](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/) can be a great alternative when accepting payments with credit card. I'm the author of the article, but it is a step by step guide to set it up.

Comment: Otherwise, checkout this [step-by-step guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-paypal-payment/) to integrate PayPal in a React component by using PayPal's REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `react-paypal-express-checkout` (***I'm the author***):

**Install**:

```
npm install --save react-paypal-express-checkout
```

**Simplest Example** (but it will show the Paypal express check out button):

```
import React from 'react';
import PaypalExpressBtn from 'react-paypal-express-checkout';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const client = {
            sandbox:    'YOUR-SANDBOX-APP-ID',
            production: 'YOUR-PRODUCTION-APP-ID',
        }   
        return (
            <PaypalExpressBtn client={client} currency={'USD'} total={1.00} />
        );
    }
}
```

==========

There is also a full example, in which you can have all types of callback function (e.g. completed payment-ID, return-URL etc.)

For full detailed document (as well as official guides from Paypal,) please go here:

https://github.com/thinhvo0108/react-paypal-express-checkout